# search an array (videos) with start and end duration ( in seconds) to find the full length video

Tags: php, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of video clips with start and end seconds duration. These video clips have same audio as background. I want to grab set of clips which should have proper or as close as possible set of seconds so it could form a full video. My aim is to find the short clips and merge them with original audio as background. Its kind of dubbing. So I need to keep the number of gaps in a video minimum. For example I have following array of clips:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 28
            [clip_id] => 1
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 193
            [clip_id] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 18
            [clip_id] => 5
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 193
            [clip_id] => 6
        )

    [4] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 31
            [clip_id] => 10
        )

    [5] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 13
            [clip_id] => 11
        )

    [6] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 9
            [clip_id] => 12
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 10
            [end_sec] => 21
            [clip_id] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 22
            [end_sec] => 171
            [clip_id] => 3
        )

    [9] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 29
            [end_sec] => 58
            [clip_id] => 2
        )

    [10] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 59
            [end_sec] => 60
            [clip_id] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 61
            [end_sec] => 72
            [clip_id] => 7
        )

)
```

In above array, I need to grab close combinations, you can see below, 0-9 10-21 and then 22 - 171 have no gaps of seconds in between so its good.

```
[6] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 9
            [clip_id] => 12
        )

    [7] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 10
            [end_sec] => 21
            [clip_id] => 0
        )

    [8] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 22
            [end_sec] => 171
            [clip_id] => 3
        )
```

OR this

```
[0] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 0
            [end_sec] => 28
            [clip_id] => 1
        )
 [9] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 29
            [end_sec] => 58
            [clip_id] => 2
        )
[10] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 59
            [end_sec] => 60
            [clip_id] => 0
        )

    [11] => Array
        (
            [start_sec] => 61
            [end_sec] => 72
            [clip_id] => 7
        )
```

I know we can not always find the best as there will many clips and many combinations but I need to find good enough to build a main video. Any guidance or help will be highly appreciated as I already have spent much time on this :)

Comment: Sounds very interesting. I know how to do this recursively and can write a solution for quadratic time - `O(n*n)`. I guess, it's ok if you aren't going to have an array of 100000 clips :) At the same time, I am sure that there is a beautiful and smart linear algorithm. For example, using combinatorial optimization.

Comment: That will be brilliant ;-) no it will not have such number of clips.

Comment: Oh, no. It won't be quadratic. It will be polynomial :( However, I am still trying to implement it.

Comment: and how big can be clip be ? when do you know that its enough ? or do you want to create sub-clips ?

Comment: actually we already know the full length of the audio song. So let say all these clips have M.J song Thriller as background so we know what is full length of that song, We will set a end point so if a short clip start from 0 or anypoint and has end sec = 330 but Thriller is not that long so we will skip that.

Comment: In your array you have `[start_sec] => 0, [end_sec] => 193, [clip_id] => 6`. Why does it end at 193 second? How can I know that the movie is of length 171?

Comment: $end = 200; let say we have defined in start that end point is 200. And also one thing to notice that our main array will not have end second more than 200 for that song. So we should not worry about the point that any clip will have end second more than the end second of its master audio.

Comment: Infact if the combination returns us clips which will cover only 100 seconds of a song (which has 180 seconds in real) then its fine. We will only use that 100 seconds of clips.

Comment: Are you expecting absolutely no gaps, or will you accept some gaps, and is there a maximum gap? e.g., would `{0-28, 29-58, 61-72}` be acceptable? Also, can clips overlap, like {4-10, 8-22}?

Comment: The questions you asked are the perfect in terms to understand what I want :) Yes I accept gaps and no actually there should be no overlaps, {4-10, 11-22} is fine but not {4-10, 8-22} as you mentioned. Thank you v much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's something that tries to maximize the total length of the clips from the starting point, only allowing a gap of 1 second between clips' end and start times as you showed in your example, which can be adjusted as you need (to widen the maximum gap or return more combinations, for example). This example assumes the list is sorted by `start_sec` and only tests paths starting at `start_sec = 0`:

```php
$data = Array
(
    0 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 0,
            'end_sec' => 28,
            'clip_id' => 1
        ),

    1 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 0,
            'end_sec' => 193,
            'clip_id' => 4
        ),

    2 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 0,
            'end_sec' => 18,
            'clip_id' => 5
        ),

    3 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 0,
            'end_sec' => 193,
            'clip_id' => 6
        ),

    4 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 0,
            'end_sec' => 31,
            'clip_id' => 10
        ),

    5 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 0,
            'end_sec' => 13,
            'clip_id' => 11
        ),

    6 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 0,
            'end_sec' => 9,
            'clip_id' => 12
        ),

    7 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 10,
            'end_sec' => 21,
            'clip_id' => 0
        ),

    8 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 22,
            'end_sec' => 171,
            'clip_id' => 3
        ),

    9 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 29,
            'end_sec' => 58,
            'clip_id' => 2
        ),

    10 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 29,
            'end_sec' => 53,
            'clip_id' => 8
        ),

    11 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 59,
            'end_sec' => 60,
            'clip_id' => 9
        ),

    12 => Array
        (
            'start_sec' => 61,
            'end_sec' => 72,
            'clip_id' => 7
        )
);
```

---

```php
function gap($i,$j,&$arr){
  return $arr[$j]['start_sec'] - $arr[$i]['end_sec'];
}

function length($i,&$arr){
  return $arr[$i]['end_sec'] - $arr[$i]['start_sec'];
}

$n = count($data);

function f($i,$prev,$len,&$arr,$clips){
  global $n;

  if ($i == $n){
    return [$len,$clips];
  }
  if (gap($prev,$i,$arr) != 1){
    return f($i + 1,$prev,$len,$arr,$clips);
  } else {
    list($a,$ac) = f($i + 1,$i,$len + length($i,$arr),$arr,$clips);
    list($b,$bc) = f($i + 1,$prev,$len,$arr,$clips);
    if ($a > $b){
      array_splice($ac,1,0,$i);
      return [$a,$ac];
    } else {
      return [$b,$bc];
    }
  }
}

$i = 0;
while ($data[$i]['start_sec'] == 0){
  echo json_encode(f($i + 1,$i,length($i,$data),$data,[$i++])) . "\n";
}
```

Output:

```php
[69,[0,9,11,12]]
[193,[1]]
[18,[2]]
[193,[3]]
[31,[4]]
[13,[5]]
[169,[6,7,8]]
```

Comment: Dear @גלעד-ברקן, I need your help to fix this algo since it is not working always. It does not return proper sorted combination if there are more than one clip where start second is 0. So let say the first 2 index of main array has the clips where start seconds are 0. The algorithim mostly returns only one result in each combination. So the combination will only return the result where start second is zero.

Comment: Here is sorted array which our algorithm generated.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 7
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 0
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 36
            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                )

        )
)

Comment: @99Points thank you for finding a bug. Please provide a link to example data that causes the problem. I'll take a look.

Answer (score 0):

the script below will sort your video clips out in the order you like. It should do what you want. use PHP MultiSort.

```
 <?PHP
/**
**Sample Array DATA I BUILT TO TEST IT
**/

    $data = array
    (
      array(
            'start_sec' => 0,
            'end_sec' => 28,
            'clip_id' => 1,
            ),
      array(
        'start_sec' => 29,
        'end_sec' => 58,
        'clip_id' => 2,
        ),
        array(
        'start_sec' => 61,
        'end_sec' => 72,
        'clip_id' => 7,
        ),
      array(
        'start_sec' => 59,
        'end_sec' => 60,
        'clip_id' => 0,
        ),
        array(
        'start_sec' =>79,
        'end_sec' => 85,
        'clip_id' => 0,
        ),
        array(
        'start_sec' => 73,
        'end_sec' => 78,
        'clip_id' => 0,
        ),
    );

    // Gets the list
    foreach ($data as $key => $row) {
        $start_sec[$key]  = $row['start_sec'];
        $end_sec[$key] = $row['end_sec'];
    }

    // Sort the data
    array_multisort($start_sec, SORT_ASC, $end_sec, SORT_ASC, $data);


    var_dump($data);
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I need best combinations :( sorting the array will not solve my problem actually.